# ImageCommandColumn Click event not fired when i palced it in Asp.net master page

Tags: master-pages, ext.net

> Hi,  I am working with Ext.net gridPanel, which has ImageCommandColumn
>   as one column, when i click on particular image button, that is fired
>   and call one Directmethod in common .aspx page. But when i place the
>   Same code in contenPage which is loaded in asp.net master page the
>   Click Event for the ImageCommandColumn is not firing in Gridpanel.
>
> what should i have to do, to work with masterpage and content page
>   scenario with gridpanel.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a test case.

Comment: it's Ok it is resolved.. it is IE10 issue..

Comment: We do support IE10. So, we would be happy to investigate a test case if you can provide.